# Django Python - Ajax POST multi array error 500

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

**view.py**

```
`for table in request.DATA["table"]:
            cc = ChechupControl(
                control= table[0],
                comment = table[1],
                isChecked = table[2],
                image= table[3]
            )
            cc.save()`
```

**Here is my ajax:**

```
`var row_table = []
                $('#car-control-sum tr').each(function (http) {
                var control= this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                var comment = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                var isChecked = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                var picture = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                row_table.push([kontrollpunkt, comment, isChecked, picture]);
            });
            console.log(row_table);
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost:8000/add-checkups/",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                    'table': row_table
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                        alert("ok")
            });`
```

I want to save each row of the table from html to db. When I run ajax django show an error:

```
`"Key 'table' not found in <QueryDict: {u'table[1][]': [u'Lys', u'asd', u'True', u'asd'], u'table[0][]': [u'Kontrollpunkt', u'Kommentar', u'True', u'asd']}>"`
```

Where is the problem and what should I do?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is the key you need `table[1][]` instead of 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

Post array may causing the problem, I don't know why .
But you can try `JSON.stringify(array)`  : array to string in json way.
So

```
var row_table = []
                $('#car-control-sum tr').each(function (http) {
                var control= this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                var comment = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                var isChecked = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                var picture = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
                row_table.push([kontrollpunkt, comment, isChecked, picture]);
            });
            console.log(row_table);
            row_table_jsonstring = JSON.stringify(row_table)
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost:8000/add-checkups/",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                    'table': row_table_jsonstring
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                        alert("ok")
            });
```

then in django:

```
import json
table_list=json.loads(request.POST['table'])
"""deal with table_list"""
```